# Determining the unknown coefficient in a differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

So I have this differential equation:
$$y''-2cy'+4y=0$$
The general solution to this equation would be
$$y(x)=C_1 e^{{(\sqrt{c^2-4}+c)}x} + C_2 e^{{(c-\sqrt{c^2-4})}x} $$
My question is how can I find all real numbers c so that $y(0)=y(2\pi)=0$

Comment: If $\sqrt{c^2-4}\geq 0$, then $y(x)$ is the sum of two exponentials and can have at most 2 roots. Try setting $c<2$ and rewriting your solution in terms of $\sin$ and $\cos$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I will try that.

Comment: There is always a solution with $y(0)=y(2\pi)=0$, namely $y=0$.  Do you mean you want there to be a **non-constant** solution with $y(0)=y(2\pi) = 0$?

Comment: The solution should be non-constant and not the trivial zero function.

Comment: The only solution as Robert pointed out is the constant solution $y=0$ otherwise you have no solution